# pynacl fails, while building (setup.py)

Tags: python, pip, debian, nacl-cryptography, pynacl

I have tried in multiple environments, debian 8, ubuntu 14.04, and ubuntu 16.04 and when I try to install pynacl it gives this error

```
Collecting pynacl
  Downloading PyNaCl-1.1.2.tar.gz (3.1MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.1MB 482kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pynacl)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.4.1 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pynacl)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from cffi>=1.4.1->pynacl)
Installing collected packages: pynacl
  Running setup.py install for pynacl ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-0jn9smso/pynacl/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-p98b0l22-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/nacl
    copying src/nacl/hash.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/nacl
    copying src/nacl/hashlib.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/nacl
    copying src/nacl/signing.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/nacl
    copying src/nacl/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/nacl
    copying src/nacl/public.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/nacl
    copying src/nacl/secret.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/nacl
    copying src/nacl/pwhash.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/nacl
    copying src/nacl/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/nacl
    copying src/nacl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/nacl
    copying src/nacl/encoding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/nacl
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/nacl/bindings
    copying src/nacl/bindings/crypto_box.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/nacl/bindings
    copying src/nacl/bindings/crypto_hash.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/nacl/bindings
    copying src/nacl/bindings/crypto_scalarmult.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/nacl/bindings
    copying src/nacl/bindings/randombytes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/nacl/bindings
    copying src/nacl/bindings/crypto_pwhash.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/nacl/bindings
    copying src/nacl/bindings/crypto_sign.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/nacl/bindings
    copying src/nacl/bindings/crypto_generichash.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/nacl/bindings
    copying src/nacl/bindings/sodium_core.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/nacl/bindings
    copying src/nacl/bindings/crypto_shorthash.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/nacl/bindings
    copying src/nacl/bindings/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/nacl/bindings
    copying src/nacl/bindings/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/nacl/bindings
    copying src/nacl/bindings/crypto_secretbox.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/nacl/bindings
    running build_clib
    configure: error: working directory cannot be determined
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-0jn9smso/pynacl/setup.py", line 232, in <module>
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6",
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/command/install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/install.py", line 583, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-0jn9smso/pynacl/setup.py", line 159, in run
        cwd=build_temp,
      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 581, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/tmp/pip-build-0jn9smso/pynacl/src/libsodium/configure', '--disable-shared', '--enable-static', '--disable-debug', '--disable-dependency-tracking', '--with-pic', '--prefix', '/tmp/pip-build-0jn9smso/pynacl/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5']' returned non-zero exit status 255

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-0jn9smso/pynacl/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-p98b0l22-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-0jn9smso/pynacl/
```

Comment: What is your working directory?

Comment: A folder within the home directory? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: @jordanm is that in the sys.path, and I don't know if this helps, but the first item in sys.path is blank